How to efficiently find a "dominant path" in a DAG?
I’m working on a graph problem involving a graph with N nodes and M bidirectional edges. I’ve used Dijkstra's algorithm to construct a Shortest Path Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) from this graph, starting from a source node S to a target node T
Given the DAG constructed using Dijkstra's algorithm, I need to find a special path from  to . This path should have the property that it shares at least one edge with every other possible path from  to  in the DAG. In other words, I’m looking for a path that "dominates" other paths by intersecting with each of them on at least one edge.
For example, in a graph with edges: 1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 6, 5 -> 6
Possible paths from 1 to 6 are: 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 6, 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 6, 1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6
Then the path 1 -> 3- > 4 -> 6 is a "dominant path" because:

It shares the edge 4 -> 6 with the path 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 6
It shares the edge 1 -> 3 with the path 1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6

figure
figure 2
The blue paths are a "dominant path".
I’m wondering if there is an efficient algorithm to identify such a "dominant path" in polynomial time if we can. Is this a known problem in graph theory, or is there a related concept that I could use to approach this problem?
I initially attempted to solve this problem by generating all possible paths from  to  in the DAG and then checking each path against all others in a brute-force.
However, this brute-force method quickly became impractical as the number of paths increased. I'm looking for a more efficient solution that can find the "dominant path" within polynomial time.

In a tree (including a SPT), there is only one path from S to T

Sorry for that I used wrong term, it's not SPT. It's a shortest path DAG that can be constructed by Dijkstra

Not sure if this helps, but iteratively searching for a bridge which separates source and terminal may help.

Thanks for your comment, It seems similar to my problem.
